# HTML elements to share some style and certain HTML elements to add specific style using CSS

Tags: html, css, class

I have multiple buttons (input type="submit"). I want all the buttons to share a same style except for one button where I need to give width and height as auto.

Using class for common style and id for a specific style didn't seem to work.

Comment: Please include the relevant code along with your question. Preferably as a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: What you are describing should work, so please show a code example.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:
HTML:

```
<input type='submit' class='one'>
<input type='submit' class='one'>
<input type='submit' class='one'>
<input type='submit' class='one'>
<input type='submit' class='one'>
<input type='submit' class='two one'>
```

CSS:

```
input.one {
    //your style here
}
input.two {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select all submit buttons like this:

```
input[type=submit] {
    /*styles for normal buttons*/
}
```

To select a single button, you would be better off using an ID:

```
#special_button {
    /*styles for special button*/
}
```

Be sure you include the styles in the order given so that they override properly.

Comment: The problem with this answer is that the OP would like to style all buttons *except* for one.   This answer provides the same style to all buttons.

Comment: i'd like to have multiple forms in the same webpage (say a login form and signup form).

Comment: i want to add a particular style to one button.. rest of the properties can be same as the other buttons. I don't want to write duplicate style for all the buttons..